# Laravel 5.3 inner join not working properly

Tags: laravel, inner-join, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

I'm having two tables as 'jobs' and 'desired_skills'.
Table structure is as follows.

jobs table
[jobs Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4ksh.png)

desired_skills table
[desired_skils table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63bbu.png)

where desired_skills.job_id refers to jobs.job id

In controller I have (I am getting $id as an argument from the url, and I can confirm the argument grabs the desired value)

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')->where(function ($query) use ($id) {
    $query->Join('desired_skills', 'desired_skills.job_id', '=', 'jobs.job_id')
    ->where('jobs.employer_id', '=', $id);
    ->select('*')
})->get();
```

when I dump and die $jobs it only returns values from jobs table.
but when I run the query

`SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN desired_skills ON desired_skills.job_id = jobs.job_id` it returns the desired value set.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you ever heared about [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) ?!

Comment: yep but with further development its gonna get hard with eloquent. so I chose query building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with wrapping your join inside of a where clause.  I don't think it's giving you your desired query with that there.

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
    ->join('desired_skills', 'desired_skills.job_id', '=', 'jobs.job_id')
    ->where('jobs.employer_id', '=', $id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks man. it woked. :) wonder what happened there with wrapping. thanks again for quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
                ->join('desired_skills', 'desired_skills.job_id', '=', 'jobs.job_id')
                ->select('jobs.*', 'desired_skills.*')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query `SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN desired_skills ON desired_skills.job_id = jobs.job_id`
is not the same has what you are trying to do in the function. In this query there is not
mention of 'employer_id' in the table 'jobs'.

An alternative would be to use eloquent relationships, as refered in a comment.

You need 3 classes in models:

Employer
Job
DesiredSkill

Between Employer and Job -> [one-to-many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) (an employer can have multiple jobs).

Between DesiredSkill and Job -> [one-to-one relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

I'm not sure what you are trying to get from the join, but i think that if you implement
the methods that allow the relationships i believe you solve whatever.

```
class Job extends Model
{

    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Job');
    }
}

class Employer extends Model
{

    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employer');
    }

    public function desiredSkill()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\DesiredSkill');
    }
}

class DesiredSkill extends Model
{

    public function job()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\DesiredSkill');
    }
}
```